# clojure - if-let syntax

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am trying to refactor this code to use `if-let`:

```
om/IWillMount
  (will-mount [_]
    (go (while true
          (if (om/get-state owner :is-loaded)
            (let [updated-world (<! (update-world (:dimensions opts) (:world @data)))]
              (om/transact! data #(assoc % :world updated-world))
              (swap! app-state assoc :world updated-world))
            (let [world (<! (get-world (:dimensions opts)))]
              (om/set-state! owner :is-loaded true)
              (om/transact! data #(assoc % :world world))
              (swap! app-state assoc :world world)))
          (<! (timeout (:poll-interval opts))))))
```

So far I have tried this:

```
om/IWillMount
  (will-mount [_]
    (go (while true
          (if-let [world (om/get-state owner :is-loaded)]
                    (<! (update-world (:dimensions opts) (:world @data)))
                    (<! (get-world (:dimensions opts)))
              (om/set-state! owner :is-loaded true)
              (om/transact! data #(assoc % :world world))
              (swap! app-state assoc :world world))
          (<! (timeout (:poll-interval opts))))))
```

But I get this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: if-let requires 1 or 2
>   forms after binding vector in web-game-of-life.app:58

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### if-let is not applicable...

The `if-let` macro is not applicable here. In an `if-let`, the result of the binding form is used as the test. It condenses code like

```
(let [world (get-world ...)]
   (if world
     (do-something-with world)
     (do-something-else)))
```

if, for example, `get-world` were to return `nil` when there was no world retrieved.

In your case value you want to test is different than the value you want to bind. You are testing `(om/get-state owner :is-loaded)` but not otherwise using the result.

### ...but duplicate code can be factored out

Your code does have duplication though, so there is a factoring opportunity. First, the same code with the first binding symbol changed to match the second, with the duplicated lines marked.

```
          (if (om/get-state owner :is-loaded)
            (let [world (<! (update-world (:dimensions opts) (:world @data)))]
(1)           (om/transact! data #(assoc % :world world))
(2)           (swap! app-state assoc :world world))
            (let [world (<! (get-world (:dimensions opts)))]
              (om/set-state! owner :is-loaded true)
(1)           (om/transact! data #(assoc % :world world))
(2)           (swap! app-state assoc :world world)))
```

Now factored by inverting the `if` and the `let`

```
(let [world (if (om/get-state owner :is-loaded) 
              (<! (update-world (:dimensions opts) (:world @data)))
              (do
                (om/set-state! owner :is-loaded true) 
                (<! (get-world (:dimensions opts)))))] 
  (om/transact! data #(assoc % :world world)) 
  (swap! app-state assoc :world world))
```

Comment: I ended up refactoring to this https://gist.github.com/dagda1/4c8034ea42ad23b2e2d6.  Why is the do block necessary in your example?

Comment: @dagda1 Unlike `when`, `if` does not have an implicit `do`. So if you want more than one form for the then or else clauses, you have to be explicit.

Answer (score 2):

[`if-let`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/if-let), like [`if`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/if) expects that the expects either 2 or 3 parameters, where the second is evaluated if the condition is true, and the optional third is evaluated if the condition if false. You can use [`do`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/do) to evaluate more than one statements in such cases.

Comment: In Addition: With `do` you can combine a whole block which shall be executed on the right place. For example: `(do statement1 statement2 ...)`